# Command to replace a string with another string with a slash

Tags: linux, sed

I can't find the mistake in my command. I want to replace

```
/home/data/newfiles with /home/data/data1/newfiles
```

I used

```
 sed -i 's/data/data/data1/g' filename
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '/home/data/newfiles' | sed 's#\(/home/data\)\(/newfiles\)#\1/data1\2#'
/home/data/data1/newfiles
```

Answer (score 0):

The replacement string can't contain the separator unbackslashed (neither can the regular expression, but that's not a problem here).

```
sed -i 's/data/data\/data1/g' filename
```

or, use a different separator

```
sed -i 's=data=data/data1=g' filename
```